# App using android google maps v2 crashes on start

Tags: maps, android-manifest, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

Everytime I've tried to test my app on my phone, the app opens quickly, shows a white screen and then closes right after. It then shows a prompt that says "Unfortunately, the app has stopped."

I have already checked the build path, I've made sure that Google play services library is added. I've tried searching several threads already on how to fix and none of them are working. So I've made this post as a last resort to get someone to check it manually.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.vendsale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

{
    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    LocationClient mNewLocationClient;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng userLocation;
    private DatabaseConnector dbConnector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkGooglePlayServicesAvailability();

        dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext());
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.getUiSettings();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mNewLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mNewLocationClient.connect();

        userLocation = new LatLng(mNewLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .getLatitude(), mNewLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vendsale"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.vendsale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.vendsale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.vendsale.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity Main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/map"
        android:onClick="onClick_Search"
        android:text="@string/ButtonText"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/message"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the supportmapfragment class in your xml.

Add this import import `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;`

and change your map intialisation line as:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
```

I am assuming the `mNewLocationClient` part in your code is working correctly and there are no nullpointers there.